# Power BI, matrix subtotal formatting

Tags: powerbi

In  can I format the matrix subtotal and total rows so that they look different from the rest of rows(text format, color, size... e.t.c.)? I mean all the row not only the numbers that are by default bold, but also the text part.
Can anyone provide me with a relevant code? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Exh.jpg)
 I mean to format also  column, not only the values.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can, as long as you have data in the matrix visualization, you will have access to this field in the formatting options under "Subtotals":

[image]

Here, you can format colors, text size and font.

Comment: I mean to format also <store> column, not only the values. (see the link)

Comment: This is also possible on the same ribbon under "Row Headers"